# Adding element to IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, generics

I have two  IEnumerable objects, if a specific condition is met, i need to take each element from first  IEnumerable  to second  IEnumerable. My code is like this

```
IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> nodesTemp = posts.Take(10).ToList();
IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> nodes = null;
foreach (var n in nodesTemp)
{
    if (condition=true)
    {
        nodes.add(n);           
    }
}
```

But this throws an error

> : 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent>' does not contain a definition for 'add' and no extension method 'add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Complete code for reference

```
 IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> nodesTemp = posts.Take(count).ToList();

IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> nodes = null;
foreach (IPublishedContent n in nodesTemp)
{
    var rolename = n.GetProperty("focusedUserGroup").Value.ToString();
    var username = umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member.Member.GetCurrentMember().Text;
    var flag = false;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rolename))
    {
        var groups = rolename.Split(',');

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(username, group))
            {
                nodes.add(n);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can not add in `IEnumerable` it's read only. take a `List`

Comment: @Div Can you suggest any work around so that i can take some specific item fron one IEnumerable  to another?

Comment: @StuartLC as i have shown above my "if condition" is too big to be included in a single linq querry

Comment: It can be thousand of code lines. But you always can put it in fucntion. Then just use it in query.

Comment: @Athul `List <IPublishedContent> nodes = new list<IPublishedContent>();`

Comment: No difference - you can refactor your predicate into as many functions as you like. Ultimately, all that 'condition' needs to be is a  `Func<IPublishedContent, bool>`

Comment: Div's comment could be right. If you declare `nodes` as `var nodes = new List<IPublishedContent>();` instead of `= null` before the loop, you can `.Add` (capital A) to that `List<>`. Such a `List<>` is implements `IEnumerable<>` (and the latter interface is even covariant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this. The reason is because IEnumerable just represents iterator over some collection. It can be array in memory, select from remote database, or even constant call like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> GetSomeConsts()
{
    yield return 1;
    yield return 101;
    yield return 22;
}
```

What you can do is to expand post iterator of your first collection. For example like this:

```
bool IsCondition(IPublishedContent n)
{
    var rolename = n.GetProperty("focusedUserGroup").Value.ToString();
    var username = umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member.Member.GetCurrentMember().Text;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rolename))
    {
        var groups = rolename.Split(',');

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(username, group))
            {
                 return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then just call it like this:

```
var nodes = posts.Take(count).Where(IsCondition);
```

Comment: Can you suggest any work around so that i can take some specific item fron one IEnumerable  to another?

Comment: In fact, you should be able to abbreviate the final for loop as well, into `return groups.Any(grp => Roles.IsUserInRole(username, grp));`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a great example of what you can use yield return for

eg:

```
public IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> Whatever(IEnmerable<IPublishedContent> nodes, int count)
{
    foreach(var node in nodes.Take(count))
    {
        var rolename = node.GetProperty("focusedUserGroup").Value.ToString();
        var username = umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member.Member.GetCurrentMember().Text;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rolename))
        {
            var groups = rolename.Split(',');

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                if (Roles.IsUserInRole(username, group))
                {
                     yield return node; //yield return allows you to create a new enumerable inline
                     break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

yield return will execute your code while you enumerate it, so if you were to call Whatever(...).First() it would only run through the code until it found the first yield return.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're filtering an IEnumerable.

In such a case, you don't need to turn it into a list first, and you can use `Enumerable<T>.Where()` to filter it.

Something like this should work:

```
var nodesTemp = posts.Take(10);
var nodes = nodesTemp.Where(item => predicate(item));
```

Where `predicate(item)` is some function that takes a parameter of type `IPublishedContent` and returns a `bool`.

You can write that as a lambda expression, for example:

```
var nodesTemp = posts.Take(10);
var nodes = nodesTemp.Where(item => item.SomeProperty == someTargetValue);
```

If you need `nodes` to be a list rather than an `IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>`, you can turn it into a list:

```
var nodes = nodesTemp.Where(item => item.SomeProperty == someTargetValue).ToList();
```

At this point you probably don't really need `nodesTemp` (unless you're using it for debugging purposes):

```
var nodes = 
    posts.Take(10)
    .Where(item => item.SomeProperty == someTargetValue)
    .ToList();
```